# unity-firebase cloud messaging issue

Tags: android, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-admin

I have developed a game with unity and I have used 'Firebase Cloud Messaging' for push notification.
I have one problem. when I clear the received notification in tray, it seems like the message related to it is also deleted. so 'MessageReceived' is not called when I open the app.

1. I experienced this problem on android. Haven't tested it on ios yet.
2. I use firebase admin sdk for sending messages.(written with node js)

is there a way to clear notification tray without deleting the message?
thanks for any help in advance

Answer (score 1):

There is some extra setup required to route notifications when the app is not running on Android.

[See the Firebase docs for more information](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/unity/client#note_about_message_delivery_on_android)

Quote from documentation:

> When the app is not running at all and a user taps on a notification, the message is not, by default, routed through FCM's built in callbacks. In this case, message payloads are received through an Intent used to start the application.

> Messages received while the app is in the background have the content of their notification field used to populate the system tray notification, but that notification content will not be communicated to FCM. That is, FirebaseMessage.Notification will be a null.

Basically you need to use the custom launch activity bundled with Firebase Messaging instead of the default `UnityPlayerActivity`. This activity is called `MessagingUnityPlayerActivity` can can be found inside `libmessaging_unity_player_activity.jar`. You'll need to create a `AndroidManifest.xml` file to instruct the app to use this custom activity instead of the default Unity one.

Comment: Actually I had Modified my manifest according to FCM documentation and the notification works fine when I run my app by clicking on the notification. my issue is when I clear notification tray before opening the app, I don't want the message related to it to be deleted So when I open the app later, the message can be received.

Comment: Sorry, now I understand what you mean. In that case you might need to implement an API for the app to retrieve messages when it starts & don't rely purely on the notifications payload. For apps I've worked on in the past we usually have an Inbox table which stores messages sent via Push Notification or Sockets which the client can read and action. I find this solution is more robust in the long run, especially if the users opt out of Push Notifications. This all depends on the requirements of your project of course, this solution might not be the best fit in all cases.

Comment: So There is no straight way of doing this. In that case, I'll have to modify my node js server. Thanks.